# Can I read a .bak file without restoring it?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

A few years ago I had used a 3rd party product to read a full backup file and open it in SSMS just as if it was online. The .bak could be queried like any online database. I need to do that again, but can't remember the company that offered the product.  Does anyone know of a tool that will do this?

The database backup is from a huge database that will take hours to restore, so I didn't want to do that unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

After some more searching and a helpful link or two, I finally found that what I was looking for is Red Gate's SQL Virtual Restore.  Problem is, it apparently isn't around anymore. I found an informational link about it in Red Gate's site [here](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/). Great write up by Brant Fritchey on it from June 2011 [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/backup-and-recovery/object-level-recovery-with-sql-virtual-restore/)

One link I found had a comment that similar functionality is in SQL Compare Pro.  If it is, the advertising page for that product, doesn't mention that feature.